# T-SQL: accessing temporary column in Common Table Expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

Is it possible to access a temporary column that was defined in a query for a Common Table Expression?  Say I have

```
select * from myTable 

;with cte  as 
(
    select
        *, Salary * 4 as FourTimesSalary
    from 
        Employees
    where 
        Name = @name
        and ID >= 100 
)
```

Is there a way to use the temporary column `FourTimesSalary` when querying cte like so?

```
select top 2 *  
from cte  
order by FourTimesSalary, Name
```

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that.  Example:

```
with temp as
(
    select 1 as id, 2*4 as val
    UNION
    select 2 as id, 3*4 as val
)
SELECT * FROM temp ORDER BY VAL desc
```

Your example looks fine, did you get an error when you tried that or something?

Comment: Yes, the error indicated I did not have column name FourTimesSalary defined.  It turned out to be a problem within my query statement.